# Prolog: How to get a copy of the original list in a recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I am trying to get the original list from List and store it to Temp. But List gets updated during recursions so Temp can't get the original data of List before recursions. Need help on how to get the original list with the sorted sub lists so I can use them in printPerMerge. Thank you!

```
mSort(Sorted,List) :-
  length(List, N),

  copy_term(List, Temp),

  write('Temp '), tab(1),
  format('~w ',[Temp]),  nl,

    
  FLength is //(N, 2),
  SLength is N - FLength,

  length(FUnsorted, FLength),
  length(SUnsorted, SLength),

  append(FUnsorted, SUnsorted, List),

  mSort(FSorted, FUnsorted),
  mSort(SSorted, SUnsorted),

  combine(Sorted, FSorted, SSorted), 

  printPerMerge(Sorted, Temp),

  write('Sorted '), tab(1),
  format('~w ',[Sorted]),  nl.
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you give some example inputs and outputs you require? Also, if your predicate has multiple clauses, you need to show them too.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to implement a merge sort. With a merge sort, there's really no need to look at list length, or pre-construct lists of the desired length.

Try something like this:

```
merge_sort( []          , []     ) .  % The empty list is ordered, is it not?
merge_sort( [X]         , [X]    ) .  % A list of length 1 is ordered, is it not?
merge_sort( [X,Y|Zs]    , Sorted ) :- % A list of length > 1 is not [necessarily] sorted, so....
    partition([X,Y|Zs], Ls, Rs) ,     % - Split the unordered list into two lists of equal length
    merge_sort(Ls,L1) ,               % - Recursively sort one sublist
    merge_sort(Rs,R1) ,               % - Recursively sort the other sublist
    merge(L1,R1,Sorted)               % - And merge them together, in order
    .                                 % Easy!

partition( []       , []     , []     ) .
partition( [X]      , [X]    , []     ) .
partition( [X,Y|Zs] , [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- partition(Zs,Xs,Ys).

merge( []     , []     , []     ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Zs] ) :- merge(Xs,[],Zs) .
merge( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- merge([],Ys,Zs) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- X @< Y, !, merge(Xs, [Y|Ys], Zs ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- merge([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) .
```